# In a Chrome Extension, using React, how can you replace an old listener that references old state?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I have an issue in a component where I'm simply using `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`, where my listener is dependent on the current component's state.

---

The problem is that when the state of the component updates, this listener is old, and is referencing an old state value. I have seen people use a ref (so they can access `.current` at invocation to get the fresh value) but I find it hard to believe this is the real answer, since my state will need to be duplicated as refs.

I think the real solution would be `useEffect` to `removeListener(oldListener)` and `addListener(newListener)` but this has the problem where I now need to keep track of my old listener.

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here; how can I maintain a listener that references current state?